# Mapping the wlceventd logs and their wlceventd_proc_event

Tags: logging, event-log, asus, asuswrt-merlin, asuswrt

I'm trying to monitor the logs that my Asus router are generating, so I can react on certain events.

Some of the interesting ones are from the Wireless LAN Controller event daemon (wlceventd), e.g. Disassoc - devices are leaving Wi-Fi:

```
wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(511): eth7: Disassoc AB:CD:EF:01:23:45, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8), rssi:0
```

I noticed that the wlceventd_proc_event seems to indicate the type of event that is logged. The `511` always seems to be Disassoc events.

I have been trying to locate the specifications of the wlceventd logs. The AsusWRT-Merlin source repository only contains the binaries of wlceventd.

What kind of wlceventd_proc_event types are there? What is the structure of the log lines? What are the different parts, e.g. eth7, status, rssi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the community.

The structure of the log message is:

- Source (wlceventd daemon)
- Message type (wlceventd_proc_event)
- Event ID (511) *The IDs are not standardized across devices/manufacturers/versions/etc*
- Event location (eth7) *The ID the system uses to identify this radio. This isn't standardized either, ethN is just how this system refers to them.*
- Event (Disassociation of client AB:CD:EF:01:23:45)
- Event status (0 = success)
- Event reason (client left the Basic Service Set the AP offers)
- Current RSSI (Received Signal Strength Indicator) *As the client's left the BSS, the radio isn't receiving a signal from it anymore, thus RSSI = 0.*

The most relevant parts of the message start from the event location. The reason and status codes are standardized by 802.11.

- [This Cisco Meraki page](https://documentation.meraki.com/MR/Wi-Fi_Basics_and_Best_Practices/802.11_Association_Process_Explained) describes the 802.11 association process.
- [This Aruba page](https://blogs.arubanetworks.com/industries/802-11-reason-codes-and-status-codes/) shows the reason and status codes - these are basically the possible event types. If the network uses RADIUS, TACACS or similar to authenticate clients/users, also 802.1X authentication events will be present.
- [Here](https://community.cisco.com/t5/wireless-mobility-knowledge-base/802-11-association-status-802-11-deauth-reason-codes/ta-p/3148055) are the reason and status codes from Cisco community - more legible but lacking the extra info Aruba page offers. Note that the many "NOT SUPPORTED" -explanations refer only to specific Cisco devices.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. Do you know if there is a specification on the Asus event id?

Comment: Apparently not. I'm not familiar with wlceventd myself, so I had to do a bit of digging, and I bumped into other similar questions pertaining to several Asus routers where "Disassociation" was indicated with different event IDs. That's why I never really pay attention to them - even if I'm scripting to analyze a log I rely on the event descriptions or the standardized status / reason codes. You could check this by googling 'wlceventd_proc_event disassoc' - I didn't dig deep enough to identify if the same models always show the same event IDs.